# Get size and position of rotated rectangle after using cv2.resize

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image with e.g. `Width=999` and `Height=767`. I know the contour of my ROI and have used `rect=cv2.minAreaRect()` to get the `CenterPosition`, `Width`, `Height` and `Angle` of the `rotated rectangle` around it. Now I need to resize the image to the size of another image with e.g. `Width=4096` and `Height=2160`. So far I am using `cv2.resize()` to do so.

My problem now is, that of course also the `boxPoints` of my rectangle take place somewhere else and the data in `rect` about `CenterPosition`, `Width`, `Height` and `Angle` of the `rotated rectangle` around the now resized ROI is not updated and so false. I have tried different workarounds, but didn't find any solution yet.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

#Create black image
img = np.zeros((767, 999, 3), np.uint8)   

#Turn ROI to white
cv2.fillConvexPoly(img, np.array(ROI_contour), (255, 255, 255))   

#Get Width, Height, and Angle of rectangle around ROI
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(np.array(ROI_contour))

#Draw rotated rectangle in red   
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
cv2.drawContours(img,[box], 0, (0,0,255), 1)   

#Resize img to new size
img_resized = cv2.resize(img, (4096, 2160), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

Here is how `img` e.g. could look like:

img with ROI in white before resizing - CenterPosition, Width, Height and Angle of ROI is known by rect.

[image]

How can I get new Width, Height and Angle of the resized ROI?

Comment: h(new) / h(old) and w(new) / w(old) will give you the new values right? Basic Math here!

Answer (score 3):

This is simple [unitary method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_method).

In your example, h_old = 767, w_old = 999; h_new = 4096, w_new = 2160.

h_ratio = h_new / h_old = 5.34, w_ratio = w_new / w_old = 2.16

Say the center_position, width and height of the rectangle found in **old** image is: (old_center_x, old_center_y), old_rect_width and old_rect_height, respectively.

Then the new values would become:

(old_center_x * w_ratio, old_center_y * h_ratio), old_rect_width * w_ratio, old_rect_height * h_ratio, respectively.

Since the aspect ratio of the two images is also not the same, 
old_aspect_ratio = 999/767 = 1.30, new_aspect_ratio = 2160 / 4096 = 0.52, you need to multiply this factor with the new dimensions too.